# How many bitcoins do bitcoin faucets give away per day on average?

Tags: faucets

I just found out about bitcoin faucets. Apparently they give away very small amounts of bitcoins (or satoshis, for that matter) in exchange for performing some minor tasks, like solving CAPTCHAs or rolling dices. How many bitcoins do these faucets give away per day on average? Are there any statistics? How profitable is it compared to bitcoin trading or mining?

Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin Faucets were useful once upon a time, when 10000 BTC still bought you only a single pizza (and even by then, they were starting to die out).

Presently, you will earn next to nothing with faucets - in fact, most faucet websites usually make you earn in DOGE or other coins with much lower values, as the time taken to earn enough BTC to be able to withdraw without losing it all to tx fees is far too large.

If your goal is to acquire BTC cheaply, your best bet would be to get a regular job and simply buy it - even $10 a day would buy you more BTC than any faucet would give to you in months.